# Why am I getting square brackets on heroku deploy? Using MERN with Axios

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, heroku, axios

I am deploying a MERN app using heroku and while the app works as expected in development, http://localhost: 3001, on deployment, I get build succeed with no errors but the website is a page that is blank except with a set of square brackets and 2 buttons  'raw'/'parsed'.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCLC3.png)]

I changed the requests on the client side from http://localhost: 3001/  to https://songlibrary.herokuapp.com/, but am still getting the same results.

Here is one of my client requests:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("https://songlibrary.herokuapp.com/").then((response) => {
          setSongList(response.data)
        })
      }, [])`
```

Here is one of my server requests

```
    router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      Song.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err)
        }
        res.send(result)
      })`
    });
```

My connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/songLibraryDB', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.connection;
```

My server/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const db = require('./config/connection');
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors())

app.use(require('./controllers/songRoutes'))

db.once('open', () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Now listening on localhost: ${PORT}`));
});
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "songlibrary",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "develop": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.16.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

Any suggests would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Brandon

I changed the requests on the client side from http://localhost: 3001/  to https://songlibrary.herokuapp.com/, but am still getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my server/index.js.  I was missing these lines

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
};
```